# JOptionPane Alternative for Android

Tags: java, android

**I have already tried Toast and Alert Dialog, and I have constantly encountered errors that made them unusable.**

Hello,

I was wondering if there is an alternative to JOptionPane that could be used for Android that lets the user type in the message box and does not just use buttons.

As I have mentioned above, I've already tried Toast and Alert Dialog, but these never seemed to work, even after several hours trying to resolve the errors.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I do suggest using **Alert Dialog**, since it's a viable alternative to JOptionPane in Java... Android's way to show interactive messages is by using Alerts. Alerts act as MessageBox or JOptionPane in J2SE. They have buttons that can be used to take decisions (Positive, Negative & Neutral buttons)

Comment: Does Alert Dialog only use buttons, or can the user type in the alert box? And if not, is there another method that can?

Comment: Yes, you can type in AlertBox and do all sorts of stuffs using custom Alert Dialog layout.. [Checkout the link from official Android docs!](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)